# Iskra sst 2030 radio speaker plug

Tags: receiver, audio-interface, repair, speaker

I was asked by a friend to take a look at an old 70-80s Iskra sst 2030 (ex Jugoslavian-slovenian company) radio. The radio seems to work fine but I can't understand which plug it uses for speakers. Any ideas?[image: plug]

Levi is left in slovenian. The rest, no clue. Here's a foto of both channels[image: plug2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, this looks very much like a ["DIN Lautsprecherstecker"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lautsprecherstecker):

[image: DIN LS]

Positive is the small hole, negative the wide slot.

Loudspeaker, if I ask google, is *zvočnik* in Slovenian – so the "ZV" label makes sense; you can switch between speaker pair 1 and 2.

Comment: That seems a good guess. Is it a dead standard or I have hope to still find it?

Comment: dead as a doornail, but so prevalent from ca 1960 to ca 1980 that you have good chances of still finding it (it was a dead standard around the mid-eighties, since these connectors really don't make a very good connection: the contact area is unnecessarily small, so it's only suitable at all for small speaker powers) Even if not: any round nail will do for the positive contact, and I'm sure you'll find something flat for the negative one.

Comment: http://de.farnell.com/schurter/4850-125/stecker-lautsprecher-gerade/dp/150850

Answer (score 3):

LEVI means LEFT

DESNI means RIGHT

ZV1 is speaker one
ZV2 is speaker two

S this radio has connections for two pairs of 4 ohm speakers. I guess LEFT ZV1 and RIGHT ZV1 are main speakers and ZV2 are additional (as option).

Each speaker connector is DIN speaker connector with two contacts. Wide contact is speaker minus, circular contact is speaker plus pole.

[image: DIN speaker connector male]

If you do not have male connectors check this: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-Pin-DIN-Hi-Fi-Speaker-Plug-Cable-Audio-Connector-PACK-of-2-Screw-Connections-/331395432695

You can easily stick speaker wires directly into female connectors as temporary solution.

Schematics

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the schematics! I have been searching then everywhere!!

Comment: So after opening the beast I am somewhat positive that the amplifier stage is kaputt, which would fit with what I read around, namely that the stage is poorly designed. Is it worth a repair?

Comment: sorry for coming back after 2 years... I'm back at looking into the amplifier stage. Could you please send me high res photos of the amplifier schematic? Thanks!

Comment: This is the best resolution i could find.

Answer (score 0):

**Both of them** . Two wires each for both the left and right stereo speakers.

"Desni" translates to *right*.

Comment: Why is this down voted?  Is it incorrect?

Comment: @Lance I'm very confident that my answer is correct. Let the guy who downvoted my answer tell us why he did.

Comment: I agree.  I was directing my question to the down-voter.  No one learns anything if someone down votes without explaining why they did.  Gave you one to balance it out...

Comment: So you mean one (ZV..) is + and the other -? I tried already and it didn't work. I suppose I have to test also the speaker then. But on the front of the radio there is a ZV2 button as well. Can be pressed or depressed